# Windows 8 metro - a number-only password text box?

Tags: windows, textbox, passwords, microsoft-metro

like when the user tap the text box, instead of popping up a full keyboard it will only pop up  a number pad, is it possible?

or if it is not possible, can we just disable the app from popping up the keyboard when we tap the box?

Comment: Is this a touch only interface?

Comment: yes indeed, sorry I forgot to mentioned it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated whether you're using C#/VB and XAML, or HTML and JavaScript. For the latter, this is very simple. When you add an input field, simply use the value "number" for the "type" attribute:

```
<input id="myNumericInput" type="number" />
```

and the soft input panel will automatically switch to numeric input when the user taps on the field.

The equivalent for XAML is to use InputScope, which is also set to "Number" (uppercase N):

```
<TextBox x:Name="myNumericTextbox" InputScope="Number" Width="500" Height="50"></TextBox>
```

This should likewise cause the numeric input panel to appear when the user taps the input field.

Comment: Ah. Missed the "password" part in the title, so it wasn't clear to me that you were looking to use a PasswordBox control specifically. Looks like you may be out of luck with that control, as it does not appear to support InputScope. That said, if you're willing to go to the effort to sub-class the TextBox control, perhaps you could write your own custom version that supports the important parts from PasswordBox while still supporting InputScope.

Comment: how to do validaton in normal textbox ? As WinRT doesn't has KeyChar so it's creating problem.

Comment: @Xyroid You'd be better served to start your own question, rather than adding a question to a months-old question as a comment. Of course, you should search first to see if someone may have already asked (and answered) your question already.